# How can I get the count of line in a file with different character

Tags: python, text-files, line-count

In the txt file it is composed of the following writing:

> funded_txo_count:0 funded_txo_count:0 funded_txo_count:5

I use this code to count number of specific string or character example, if I have "0" 1000 times, the output if 1000,

But what do I have to do to identify the different lines that do not contain this string or character? I mean the number of the line itself, since the txt file that I want to identify is based on each line

```
d = 0
with open("filename.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        d += line.count("0")

print(d)
```

`Output: 2`

I want to identify the other lines that do not contain the character or string 0

Identifying different characters according to the line.

Comment: What about something like `funded_txo_count:50`. Would that not count because there is a zero or would count because its the number 50?

Comment: I don't understand all of the constraints, but perhaps `sum(1 for line in open("filename.txt") if "0" in line)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not in` for a simple test of the character "0" in a line. Use `enumerate` to iterate file lines with a line count and put it all in a list comprehension.

```
line_nums = [line_num
    for line_num, line in enumerate(open("filename.txt"), 1)
    if "0" not in line]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some code to keep track of the current line number.  Also when you call `count()`, add a bit of extra processing if it did not find anything:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as in_file:
    line_number = 0
    for line in in_file:
        line_number += 1
        zero_count = line.count("0")
        if zero_count == 0:
            print(f"line {line_number} does not contain 0")
        d += zero_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly, but what you can do is this

You can get the total number of lines that the file has, and substitute from it the number of lines that have `"0"`

```
with open(r"filename.txt", 'r') as fp:
    d = 0
    lines = len(fp.readlines())
    
    for line in fp:
        d += line.count("0")

print(d)
print(f"The number of lines without 0 is ${lines-d}")
```